# Gmail email table padding being removed in actual email

Tags: html, email, gmail

I'm having a padding issue on a table in gmail.  Any help would be most appreciated.  Remember this is a gmail email, so all css must be inline unfortunately. Thanks!

It looks like this in the composed message with proper padding:
[image]

And then it appears to remove the padding in on the table in the actual email:
[image]

This is the piece of code with the padding in the td element:

```
<td background="http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/prowler3.png" style="line-height:10px; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border:0;padding-top:40px !important;padding-right:30px !important;padding-bottom:20px !important;padding-left:30px !important; background-image:url('http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/prowler3.png'); background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover -o-background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

code:

```
 <table style="max-width: 600px;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td background="http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/prowler3.png" style="line-height:10px; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border:0;padding-top:40px !important;padding-right:30px !important;padding-bottom:20px !important;padding-left:30px !important; background-image:url('http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/prowler3.png'); background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover -o-background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">

                <table width="70" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                    <tr>
                        <td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                            <img src="http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/shoemaker_repair_blue@2x-2.png"  style="height: auto; "width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" / >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            <table width="425" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 425px!important; width: 100%; max-width: 425px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="70">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; letter-spacing: 10px; padding: 0 0 0 3px;">
                                                            CREATING
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-size: 33px; line-height: 38px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
                                                            Beautiful Fitness Web Design
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is, what a nightmare.  I had to create td blocks of space and completely take out the padding.  This is the finished code, I unfortunately don't have time to make edit so you can compare using a tool.

Finished product, after about 2 hours of work:

```
<table style="width: 600px;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
                <tr>
                    <td background="http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/prowler3.png"  style="line-height:10px; background-image:url('http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/prowler3.png'); background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover -o-background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;" >

                    <table width="70" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                        <tr>
                            <td width="40px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                                <img src="http://timshoemake.io/wp-content/uploads/email-template/shoemaker_repair_blue@2x-2.png"  style="height: auto; "width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" / >
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                <table width="425" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <![endif]-->
                                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 425px; width: 100%; max-width: 425px;">

                                                <!-- top padding -->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="600px" height="40px"></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <!-- header content -->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="70">
                                                    <table width="425px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" >
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <td style="font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; letter-spacing: 10px; padding: 0 0 0 3px;">
                                                                Creating
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 38px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
                                                                Beautiful Fitness Web Design
                                                            </td>
                                                            <!-- <td width="20px"></td> -->
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <!-- bottom padding -->
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="600px" height="40px"></td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                            </td>
                                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <![endif]-->
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For it to work in Outook 2013 you need to apply this style... `style="height:40px;line-height:40px;font-size:40px;"`, as I found out when trying to set `0` height.